# OpenStack Queens: Horizon Fails after rebooting the controller node

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-keystone, openstack-horizon

The controller node was rebooted and some VMs were running. After that, when logging to Horizon, I keep receiving the following error: **Error: Unable to retrieve instances**. And I can no longer see the VMs that was running. The following is the output of **/var/log/apache2/error.log**. I am beginner and I am running out of ideas to solve the issue, any help is much appreciated.

```
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.516711 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] WARNING horizon.exceptions Recoverable error: The server is
currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.516739 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.516745 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.516750 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]  (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-88698cf2-ea4a-4bdf-99f9-32f6e49
7338f)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.648861 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ERROR openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project.trunks.panel Ca
ll to list enabled services failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Neutron endpoint. Trunks panel will not be displayed.
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.691047 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ERROR openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin.aggregates.panel Call to list supported extensions failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Nova endpoint. Host Aggregates panel will not be displayed.
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.730674 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ERROR openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin.trunks.panel Call to list enabled services failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Neutron endpoint. Trunks admin panel will not be displayed.
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785539 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ERROR openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project.instances.tables Failed to retrieve quota information
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785552 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785556 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/instances/tables.py", line 396, in allowed
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785559 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     limits = api.nova.tenant_absolute_limits(request, reserved=True)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785562 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/api/nova.py", line 907, in tenant_absolute_limits
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785566 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     tenant_id=tenant_id).absolute
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785569 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/v2/limits.py", line 100, in get
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785572 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     return self._get("/limits%s" % query_string, "limits")
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785575 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 351, in _get
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785578 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785581 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 304, in get
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785584 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785592 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 83, in request
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785596 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785598 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ClientException: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785601 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785604 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.785606 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]  (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-9b69b1fa-6832-4d2f-ac33-de6fbb9814aa)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823817 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ERROR openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project.instances.tables Failed to retrieve quota information
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823830 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823834 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/instances/tables.py", line 396, in allowed
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823837 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     limits = api.nova.tenant_absolute_limits(request, reserved=True)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823840 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/api/nova.py", line 907, in tenant_absolute_limits
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823844 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     tenant_id=tenant_id).absolute
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823847 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/v2/limits.py", line 100, in get
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823861 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823864 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 83, in request
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823867 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823870 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458] ClientException: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823873 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823876 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]
[Mon Jul 11 13:26:04.823878 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1509:tid 140620901611264] [remote 192.168.100.66:50458]  (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-3eab18f5-4d6f-4f32-b505-2d718ce
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if all other openstack services are running, like nova, neutron etc. `systemctl status openstack-nova-api.service` should show you if nova-api is running (the service responsible for managing VMs). Check all other services, too. Usually, the services should be enabled so a reboot would start them. If they are not enabled, enable them, e.g. `systemctl enable --now openstack-nova-api.service`. The `--now` flag also starts the service in case it is stopped. How did you deploy this environment? The commands may differ if it was deployed by kolla or other deployment methods.